npm run <Tab> it's not picking-up/autocompleting script names from monorepo workspaces package.json
When using npm run <Tab>, autocompletion only displays script names from the root ./package.json and doesn't include script names from package.json files in subdirectories like ./client/package.json or ./server/package.json. Even if I run npm run <Tab> from within the ./server/ subdirectory, it still only shows scripts from the root ./package.json.
Is there a way to configure autocompletion to display script names from all package.json files, or at least from the package.json located in the current directory?
This behavior is consistent on MacOS in both zsh and bash.
vscode autocomplete example img here

It looks like this is a known upstream issue. You can track it here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7114
